# Converting integer to digit list

Tags: python, list, integer, type-conversion

What is the quickest and cleanest way to convert an `integer` into a `list`?

For example, change `132` into `[1,3,2]` and `23` into `[2,3]`. I have a variable which is an `int`, and I want to be able to compare the individual digits so I thought making it into a list would be best, since I can just do `int(number[0])`, `int(number[1])` to easily convert the list element back into int for digit operations.

Answer (score 103):

Convert the integer to string first, and then use `map` to apply `int` on it:

```
>>> num = 132
>>> map(int, str(num))    #note, This will return a map object in python 3.
[1, 3, 2]
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in str(num)]
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote but it didn't return the same as you did:

>>>num  =132
>>>map(int, str(num))
<map object at 0x1aed510> (I don't know how format the comment right.)

Comment: @GinKin For Python 3 you need `list(map(int, str(num)) )`.

Comment: More on the answer can be found here: `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions` and here `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension`

Answer (score 22):

> There are already great methods already mentioned on this page, however it does seem a little obscure as to which to use. So I have added some mesurements so you can more easily decide for yourself:

---

*A large number has been used (for overhead) `1111111111111122222222222222222333333333333333333333`*

## **Using `map(int, str(num))`:**

```
import timeit

def method():
    num = 1111111111111122222222222222222333333333333333333333
    return map(int, str(num))

print(timeit.timeit("method()", setup="from __main__ import method", number=10000)
```

*Output: `0.018631496999999997`*

## **Using list comprehension:**

import timeit

```
def method():
    num = 1111111111111122222222222222222333333333333333333333
    return [int(x) for x in str(num)]

print(timeit.timeit("method()", setup="from __main__ import method", number=10000))
```

*Output: `0.28403817900000006`*

***Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905936/converting-integer-to-list-in-python/13905946#13905946)***

The results show that the first method involving inbuilt methods is much faster than list comprehension.

## **The "mathematical way":**

```
import timeit

def method():
    q = 1111111111111122222222222222222333333333333333333333
    ret = []
    while q != 0:
        q, r = divmod(q, 10) # Divide by 10, see the remainder
        ret.insert(0, r) # The remainder is the first to the right digit
    return ret

print(timeit.timeit("method()", setup="from __main__ import method", number=10000))
```

*Output: `0.38133582499999996`*

***Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905936/converting-integer-to-list-in-python/13906149#13906149)***

## **The `list(str(123))` method (does not provide the right output):**

```
import timeit

def method():
    return list(str(1111111111111122222222222222222333333333333333333333))
    
print(timeit.timeit("method()", setup="from __main__ import method", number=10000))
```

*Output: `0.028560138000000013`*

***Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905936/converting-integer-to-list-in-python/13905990#13905990)***

## **The answer by Duberly González Molinari:**

```
import timeit

def method():
    n = 1111111111111122222222222222222333333333333333333333
    l = []
    while n != 0:
        l = [n % 10] + l
        n = n // 10
    return l

print(timeit.timeit("method()", setup="from __main__ import method", number=10000))
```

*Output: `0.37039988200000007`*

***Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905936/converting-integer-to-list-in-python/45377577#45377577)***

## **Remarks:**

In all cases the `map(int, str(num))` is the fastest method (and is therefore probably the best method to use).  List comprehension is the second fastest (but the method using `map(int, str(num))` is probably the most desirable of the two.

Those that reinvent the wheel are interesting but are probably not so desirable in real use.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest and best way is already answered, but the first thing I thought of was the mathematical way, so here it is:

```
def intlist(n):
    q = n
    ret = []
    while q != 0:
        q, r = divmod(q, 10) # Divide by 10, see the remainder
        ret.insert(0, r) # The remainder is the first to the right digit
    return ret

print intlist(3)
print '-'
print intlist(10)
print '--'
print intlist(137)
```

It's just another interesting approach, you definitely don't have to use such a thing in practical use cases.

Comment: `list.insert(0, item)` is `O(n)` operation. You could use `list.append(item)` instead and reverse the list at the end: `ret[::-1]`.

Comment: Just should note this fails for 0

Answer (score 3):

```
n = int(raw_input("n= "))

def int_to_list(n):
    l = []
    while n != 0:
        l = [n % 10] + l
        n = n // 10
    return l

print int_to_list(n)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation and not just code. Explain what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Use `list` on a number converted to string:

```
In [1]: [int(x) for x in list(str(123))]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @Tim: That doesn't give a list of int but a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string like this: '123456'
and you want a list of integers like this: [1,2,3,4,5,6], use this:

```
>>>s = '123456'    
>>>list1 = [int(i) for i in list(s)]
>>>print(list1)

[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

or if you want a list of strings like this: ['1','2','3','4','5','6'], use this:

```
>>>s = '123456'    
>>>list1 = list(s)
>>>print(list1)

['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>list(map(int, str(number)))  #number is a given integer
```

It returns a list of all digits of number.

Answer (score 1):

#### you can use:

First convert the value in a string to iterate it, Them each value can be convert to a Integer `value = 12345`

`l = [ int(item) for item in str(value) ]`

Answer (score 1):

By looping it can be done the following way :)

```
num1= int(input('Enter the number'))
sum1 = num1 #making a alt int to store the value of the orginal so it wont be affected
y = [] #making a list 
while True:
    if(sum1==0):#checking if the number is not zero so it can break if it is
        break
    d = sum1%10 #last number of your integer is saved in d
    sum1 = int(sum1/10) #integer is now with out the last number ie.4320/10 become 432
    y.append(d) # appending the last number in the first place

y.reverse()#as last is in first , reversing the number to orginal form
print(y)
```

Answer becomes

```
Enter the number2342
[2, 3, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
num = 123
print(num)
num = list(str(num))
num = [int(i) for i in num]
print(num)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
num = list(str(100))
index = len(num)
while index > 0:
    index -= 1
    num[index] = int(num[index])
print(num)
```

It prints `[1, 0, 0]` object.

Answer (score -1):

Takes an integer as input and converts it into list of digits.

code:

```py
num = int(input())
print(list(str(num)))
```

output using 156789:

```py
>>> ['1', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```